# What is the difference between computer science and computer engineering in brief

Tags: computer-history, programming

For a beginner who wants to walk down the path of programming and developing and etc. **What is a *brief* explanation of the differences of the two**?

To clarify, Computer science is CS while software or computer engineering is IT what is the simple difference between IT and CS? Thank you

Comment: I think that answers to this question would be more useful if you could be explicit about *why* you have this question, or equivalently what the *context* to the question is. Are you, for example, comparing two university courses to decide which to apply for?

Comment: @PeterTaylor i am willing to save my valuable time :)

Comment: In a nutshell: Computer engineers design computing machinery. Computer scientists study the possibilities of what can be accomplished by using computing machinery.

Answer (score 6):

I think you're still slightly confused yourself, actually.  All of the fields below have a great deal of overlap because they are in similar parts of the world

**Computer Science**: Computer Science is the broad study of computational systems, which can be a little frustrating, because people often use the term to describe some specific subset.  If you major in "computer science" at a university, it is not at all clear what you will be studying after a few intro courses until you inspect the curriculum. It is perfectly possible to get a CS degree without studying almost any content from the other fields outlined below. However, *all of those terms* could possibly be called "computer science" depending on the context.

I (and some others) hold that Computer Science is purely the branch of mathematics that deals with computation. Some people try to keep things less ambiguous by adding the word *theoretical* before CS to indicate the mathematical field, but this is not always the case. (Take a look at the [Computer Science Stackexchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com) to get a sense of what I would term "CS".)

**Software Engineering**: The art and science of creating good software.

**Information Technology**: The field concerned with the hardware and software infrastructure that manages networks and data.

**Computer Engineering**: a field that mixes Electrical Engineering with Software Engineering.

**Mechatronics**: a field that combines Computer Engineering with mechanical engineering.